Struggling to edit the width of text in 'Variations' template
I am struggling, using the "Variations" template, to extend the paragraph text to fit the whole screen. I've googled and it comes up with lots of instances of variations, and I've searched these threads and tried using the CSS code recommended but it just errors. The short paragraphs look really messy so I was hoping someone could give me some assistance! Is there a plugin I haven't come across, or have I chosen a template that isn't compatible? Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
